# Effect of an interaction term in a linear model

Tags: r, lm

I am using the `effects` package to find the effect of variables in my linear model.

```
library(effects)
data(iris)

lm1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length*Petal.Width,data=iris)
```

For a simple term in the model, I can get the effects for each data point using

```
effect("Sepal.Width", lm1, xlevels=iris['Sepal.Width'])
```

How can I get a similar 1-dimensional vector of values for my interaction term at each point? Does this even make sense? Everything thing I've tried is returning a 2-d matrix e.g.

```
effect("Petal.Length:Petal.Width", lm1 ,xlevels=iris['Petal.Length']*iris['Petal.Width'])
```

I'm not sure what should be used for the the `xlevels` argument in this case to give me more than just the default 5 equally spaced points.

Comment: This is not a simple task. Here's one approach: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jtools/vignettes/interactions.html

Comment: You could create a new variable with `iris$int_petal <- interaction(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Petal.Width)` and then use this variable in your `lm`

Comment: @LAP is this completely equivalent to the normal way of having the interaction term in the formula?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Think I've figure out something which gives me what I want.

```
# Create dataframe with all possible combinations 
eff_df <- data.frame(effect("Petal.Length:Petal.Width",lm1,xlevels=list(Petal.Length=iris$Petal.Length, Petal.Width=iris$Petal.Width)))

# Create column to merge on in eff_df 
eff_df$merge_col <- paste0(eff_df$Petal.Length,eff_df$Petal.Width)

# Create column it will share in iris
iris$merge_col <- paste0(iris$Petal.Length,iris$Petal.Width)

# Only eff_df$fit values which correspond to a value in iris will be merged 
iris <- merge(iris, eff_df[,c(7,3)], by="merge_col", all.x=T)
```

Then the effects vector is stored in `iris$fit`.